# How to replace curdoc

Tags: bokeh

How can I replace the current document in a bokeh server app?

I have a previous document saved as a `json_string`. If I do

```
set_curdoc(Document.from_json_string(json_string))
```

this seems to properly change curdoc(), however the new document is not displayed in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround, other places suggest to update the children of an existing layout instead of updating the whole curdoc().

I did that but I had to expand a bit to do that from a document saved in a json string.

I had to switch the `document` attribute of all the models from the imported document to curdoc() instead (otherwise it complains that the models belong to another document)

assuming that the document I import and the current document both have only one root:

```
new_doc = Document.from_json_string(json_string)

new_grid_models = collect_models(new_doc.roots[0])

for elem in new_grid_models:
    try:
        elem.document = curdoc()
    except AttributeError:
        elem._document = curdoc()

new_children = new_doc.roots[0].children
del new_doc

grid.children = new_children
```

After that the python callbacks need to be re-affected to the appropriate imported models.

I put up an example app here:
[save_and_load app on Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/rocheseb/bokeh/src/4123c38a05144150f7e284ecec03bdd43cf1fb10/applications/?at=default)

Answer (score 0):

You can just clear the current document and then add a new one:

1. Put the whole code to create your document (bokeh app) into a function `create_curdoc()`. At the very end of this function you have `curdoc().add_root(layout)`.
2. Call the function `create_curdoc()` once to create and display the document
3. Clear the current document with `curdoc().clear()`
4. Call the function `create_curdoc()` with updated data again (or another function that creates a document) to create and display the new document.
   *If you dont clear before calling the function again the new document will just be added at the bottom of the old one.*

You could, for example, trigger the update by a button callback inside your current document.

The button setup might look like this:

```py
def replace():
    curdoc().clear()
    create_curdoc()

replace_button = Button(
    label="Replace Document",
    button_type= "danger")

replace_button.on_click(replace)
```